# How to test if a device would be able to play a video of a specific resolution?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I have this app that will make videos available for the user.

The videos will be available in several resolutions like 720p, 1080p and UHD. But I don't want to show to the users a list containing videos that their devices cannot play, that will generate frustration.

Is there a way to test if a given device will be able to play a given resolution without downloading the video and see if it plays? Is there something on iOS that provides a list of formats that can play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use UIScreen to find the height and width of the screen.

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height

if screenWidth =< 720.0 {
    //play 720 video
} else if screenWidth => 1080.0 {
    //play 1080 video
} else if screenWidth => /* Your UHD */ {
    //play UHD video
} else {
    //play default video resolution
}
```

This isn't the most practical way to achieve what you're saying, but it should give you an idea. Hope this works for you, and if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately several devices can play UHD and have screens that are much smaller. My question is if that media would be playable on such device.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure. You are right, but to find the device compatibility is a little harder to find because the device might not give that info.